# Arrays and addition in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm creating a PHP script that reads some data from a log file and adds up the amount of bytes in each line, e.g.

```
log file ($log):

data data data data 3456 data data data

data data data data 4567 data data data

...etc.
```

The code i'm using is:

```
$eachline = array();
$eachline[] = fgets($log, 1024); //makes each line an element of array
$bandwidth = 0;
$singleline = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($eachline as $i) {
  if(!empty($i)) {
      $singleline = explode(' ', $i);
      $bandwidth = $singline[4];//assign variable to element 4 the number
      $totalbandwidth +=$bandwidth;//calculate total figure
  }
}
echo"<p>$totalbandwidth</p>";
```

But it keeps returning 0, what am I doing wrong!

Comment: There is a typo at $bandwidth = $singline[4]; Change it to $singleline[4].

Comment: thanks for this! unfortunately i don't do the same typo in the code! any other ideas?

Comment: There are a couple of items you may want to address. First $totalbandwidth is declared within the control statement's scope which does not guarantee declaration outside of the control statement. I would declare $totalbandwidth along with your other variables at the top and initialize it to 0. I would also add some additional sanity checking while looping through $eachline. If you know your data source is consistently formed you could probably just add a check on $singleline[4] to make sure it is what you want before adding it. Check the data source to see how flexible your code needs to be.

Comment: Look at simon's answer as well. Right now the code is only reading in one line of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
<?php
 $eachline[] = "data data data data 3456 data data data";
 $eachline[] .= "data data data data 4567 data data data";
$alltotal = 0;
foreach ($eachline as $line) {
      if(!empty($line)) {
        preg_match('!\d+!', $line, $number);
        $alltotal += $number[0];
      }
}
echo $alltotal;
?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/518912

Answer (score 0):

Its simply because $i is still an array. So you would have to iterate that to or use the keys, in fact it is a multidimensional array.

Try to `foreach ($eachline as $i => $val) {`

And `$singleline = explode(' ', $val);`

Comment: This would not change the value of the variable passed to explode. This simply gives access to the key pointing to the value (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: He tries to pass an array to explode, which will not work. Now he can choose to explode all values in the array(array()) or pick the ones he like.

Comment: @isnisn he doesn't try to pass an array. `$i` is a string.

Comment: @simon $i is NOT a string. If i do $array[] = array("array"); and foreach($array as $i) then $i is an array.

Comment: @isnisn: He doesn't do `$array[] = array("array");`, what he does is `$array[] = "string";` since `fgets()` returns a string

Answer (score 0):

Dont't use explode function here.

Your can get numeric value from string using [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) OR [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function:-

```
$eachline[] = "data data data data 3456 data data data";
$eachline[] = "data data data data 4567 data data data";
$total = 0;  // define a variable
foreach($eachline as $line) {
      if(!empty($line)) {   
        // get integer value from string     
        $int = filter_var($line, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        // perform addition operation
        $total += $int;
      }
}
echo $total;  // print total
```

You can also replace

```
$int = filter_var($line, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

with

```
$int = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$line); // using regex
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks very much guys

Answer (score 0):

[fgets()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) returns a string, not an array. You could do something like this:

```
$eachline = array();
$totalbandwidth = 0;
while (($line = fgets($log, 1024)) !== false) {
    $eachline[] = $line;

    $singleline = array();
    $bandwidth = 0;

    if (!empty($line)) {
        $singleline = explode(' ', $line);
        $bandwidth = $singleline[4];
        $totalbandwidth += $bandwidth;
    }
}

echo "<p>$totalbandwidth</p>";
```

If you don't need the lines later, you can of course remove the `$eachline` array

Comment: Good call. A loop needs to be executed to place all of the lines into the array. As is, one line of the data is placed in an array and ran. If the first line does not have any bandwidth used that could account for the 0.